# Irrelevant columns breaking dask groupby vars, but not means (and not in pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dask, pandas-groupby

Below is the MCVE of the behavior of an up-to-date `dask` instance on my system, and contrasts the `dask` error with `pandas` using the small CSV quoted at the end of this question.

Setup:

```
import numpy as np
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv('hmda_lar_head_4var.csv',
                 engine='c',
                 usecols=['tract_to_msamd_income','as_of_year','agency_abbr','action_taken_name'],
                 dtype={'tract_to_msamd_income': np.float64,
                        'as_of_year':np.uint16,
                        'agency_abbr':'category',
                        'action_taken_name':'category'
                       })
```

The line that breaks: `df.groupby('as_of_year').var().compute()`

The error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

/Users/laszlo.sandor/miniconda3/envs/idp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/dataframe/utils.py in raise_on_meta_error(funcname)
    136     try:
--> 137         yield
    138     except Exception as e:


/Users/laszlo.sandor/miniconda3/envs/idp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py in _emulate(func, *args, **kwargs)
   3058     with raise_on_meta_error(funcname(func)):
-> 3059         return func(*_extract_meta(args, True), **_extract_meta(kwargs, True))
   3060 


/Users/laszlo.sandor/miniconda3/envs/idp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/compatibility.py in apply(func, args, kwargs)
     46         if kwargs:
---> 47             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     48         else:


/Users/laszlo.sandor/miniconda3/envs/idp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/dataframe/groupby.py in _var_agg(g, levels, ddof)
    210     result /= div
--> 211     result[(n - ddof) == 0] = np.nan
    212     assert isinstance(result, pd.DataFrame)


/Users/laszlo.sandor/miniconda3/envs/idp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   2425         elif isinstance(key, DataFrame):
-> 2426             self._setitem_frame(key, value)
   2427         else:


/Users/laszlo.sandor/miniconda3/envs/idp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _setitem_frame(self, key, value)
   2463         self._check_setitem_copy()
-> 2464         self._where(-key, value, inplace=True)
   2465 


/Users/laszlo.sandor/miniconda3/envs/idp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _where(self, cond, other, inplace, axis, level, try_cast, raise_on_error)
   4952                 if not is_bool_dtype(dt):
-> 4953                     raise ValueError(msg.format(dtype=dt))
   4954 


ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not float64


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-154-4d73414200e5> in <module>()
----> 1 df.groupby('as_of_year').var().compute()


/Users/laszlo.sandor/miniconda3/envs/idp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/dataframe/groupby.py in var(self, ddof, split_every, split_out)
    796                      combine_kwargs={'levels': levels},
    797                      split_every=split_every, split_out=split_out,
--> 798                      split_out_setup=split_out_on_index)
    799 
    800         if isinstance(self.obj, Series):


/Users/laszlo.sandor/miniconda3/envs/idp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py in apply_concat_apply(args, chunk, aggregate, combine, meta, token, chunk_kwargs, aggregate_kwargs, combine_kwargs, split_every, split_out, split_out_setup, split_out_setup_kwargs, **kwargs)
   3010         meta_chunk = _emulate(apply, chunk, args, chunk_kwargs)
   3011         meta = _emulate(apply, aggregate, [_concat([meta_chunk])],
-> 3012                         aggregate_kwargs)
   3013     meta = make_meta(meta)
   3014 


/Users/laszlo.sandor/miniconda3/envs/idp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py in _emulate(func, *args, **kwargs)
   3057     """
   3058     with raise_on_meta_error(funcname(func)):
-> 3059         return func(*_extract_meta(args, True), **_extract_meta(kwargs, True))
   3060 
   3061 


/Users/laszlo.sandor/miniconda3/envs/idp/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
     75                 value = type()
     76             try:
---> 77                 self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
     78                 raise RuntimeError("generator didn't stop after throw()")
     79             except StopIteration as exc:


/Users/laszlo.sandor/miniconda3/envs/idp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/dataframe/utils.py in raise_on_meta_error(funcname)
    148                ).format(" in `{0}`".format(funcname) if funcname else "",
    149                         repr(e), tb)
--> 150         raise ValueError(msg)
    151 
    152 


ValueError: Metadata inference failed in `apply`.

Original error is below:
------------------------
ValueError('Boolean array expected for the condition, not float64',)

Traceback:
---------
  File "/Users/laszlo.sandor/miniconda3/envs/idp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/dataframe/utils.py", line 137, in raise_on_meta_error
    yield
  File "/Users/laszlo.sandor/miniconda3/envs/idp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 3059, in _emulate
    return func(*_extract_meta(args, True), **_extract_meta(kwargs, True))
  File "/Users/laszlo.sandor/miniconda3/envs/idp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/compatibility.py", line 47, in apply
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/laszlo.sandor/miniconda3/envs/idp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/dataframe/groupby.py", line 211, in _var_agg
    result[(n - ddof) == 0] = np.nan
  File "/Users/laszlo.sandor/miniconda3/envs/idp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2426, in __setitem__
    self._setitem_frame(key, value)
  File "/Users/laszlo.sandor/miniconda3/envs/idp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2464, in _setitem_frame
    self._where(-key, value, inplace=True)
  File "/Users/laszlo.sandor/miniconda3/envs/idp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4953, in _where
    raise ValueError(msg.format(dtype=dt))
```

Compare this with the behavior of the line that produces correct results: `df.groupby('as_of_year').mean().compute()`

If you set things up in supposedly similar `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('hmda_lar_head_4var.csv',
                 engine='c',
                 usecols=['tract_to_msamd_income','as_of_year','agency_abbr','action_taken_name'],
                 dtype={'tract_to_msamd_income': np.float64,
                        'as_of_year':np.uint16,
                        'agency_abbr':'category',
                        'action_taken_name':'category'
                       })
```

You see that both `df.groupby('as_of_year').var()` and `df.groupby('as_of_year').mean()` produce the correct results.

If you load only two columns, one you are grouping by and another that is meaningful to report the variance for, `dask` has no problem reporting the variance:

```
import numpy as np
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv('hmda_lar_head_4var.csv',
                 engine='c',
                 usecols=['tract_to_msamd_income','as_of_year'],
                 dtype={'tract_to_msamd_income': np.float64,
                        'as_of_year':np.uint16
                       })
```

This is small comfort, as (I think) you cannot easily specify which columns to calculate `groupby` methods for, only select ones to report. I.e. some columns can break `dask` `groupby` `var` even if you ask to report only other columns.

Here is the CSV for MCVE:

> tract_to_msamd_income,as_of_year,agency_abbr,action_taken_name
>   "85.02999877929688","2007","FRS","Loan originated"
>   "103.12000274658203","2007","FRS","Application withdrawn by applicant"
>   "127.87000274658203","2007","FRS","Loan originated"
>   "103.12000274658203","2007","FRS","Application denied by financial institution"
>   "131.14999389648438","2007","FRS","Loan originated"
>   "85.02999877929688","2007","FRS","Application withdrawn by applicant"
>   "103.12000274658203","2007","FRS","Application withdrawn by applicant"
>   "95.76000213623047","2007","FRS","Loan originated"
>   "103.12000274658203","2007","FRS","Application withdrawn by applicant"

Comment: You can open an issue on the github: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/new My cursory guess is that it is trying to set np.nan into the intu64 which is throwing a ValueError.